# Addition of custom rows in SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to be able to add custom rows to the result set. Let's say i have the following query:

```
SELECT x, y, count(*) c
FROM cache
WHERE cache_id = 1
GROUP BY cache_key
```

An exemplary result may be:

```
x   y   c
4   5   2
12  16  6
```

Now i want to add related rows to the result set. Let's say i want to add 4 rows per result which have neighbored coordinates and a lowered count to have a result like this:

```
x   y   c
4   5   2   (original row)
3   5   1   (added rows)
5   5   1
4   4   1
4   6   1
12  16  6   (original row)
11  16  3   (added rows)
13  16  3
12  15  3
12  17  3
```

Spoken in images, instead of this:

```
    2


           6
```

i want this:

```
    1
  1 2 1
    1
           3
         3 6 3
           3
```

Is that possible with pure MySQL? The result is processed in PHP afterwards, if there is no way to achieve this.

Comment: Is this a game? If so tag it as one, you may get better answers.

Comment: No it's for heatmap generation to place on a map.

Comment: I did not found a solution for this, so i coded it in a post processing method after the SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be possible to do a self join to achieve this purely in MySQL. However, I don't think it would be *worth* the trouble.

My suggestion would be to loop over the original result set in PHP and add your neighboring coordinates. The final result would be what you need.

```
$coordinates = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  array_push($coordinates, $row);

  // perform logic to add neighboring N, S, E, W coordinates to $coordinates
}
```

Comment: This would be possible, but due to big result sets i'd prefer a solution with better performance.